# Azure redirect "m." to mobile site

Tags: asp.net, redirect, azure

I am implementing when user enters "m.co-oprating.com" it will be redirect to "www.co-oprating.com/mobile", but when I used the following code it doesn't work:

```
if (Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("m."))
            {
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
                builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.StatusCode = 301;
                Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
                Response.AddHeader("Location", "www.co-oprating.com/mobile");
                Response.End();
            }
```

Was it because the request did not reach co-oprating.com at all, do I have to fix the DNS ?

Comment: What did you try to diagnose the problem?

Comment: `It doesn't work` Tell us HOW it doesn't work. Does the new URL get rebuilt properly? `Was it because the request did not reach co-oprating.com at all, do I have to fix the DNS ?` How should we know? You're the one the running the site, you should test it out.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to fix the DNS

Yes.

```
nslookup
> m.co-oprating.com
 Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
 Address:  8.8.8.8

 *** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find m.co-oprating.com: Non-existent domain
```